# Pi 4 - usb0 showing RX errors

Tags: wifi, usb, pi-4, dhcp

I have one Pi4 as web server. I am using a TP-Link 4G LTE Router connected via usb with my Pi. I am noticing this RX errors in `ifconfig` command. This is the output:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether dc:a6:32:7f:32:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 165924  bytes 53513258 (51.0 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 165924  bytes 53513258 (51.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.188  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::75dc:b20d:5ce8:7a45  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether ae:fd:b9:3b:1a:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 230621  bytes 88096074 (84.0 MiB)
    RX errors 15  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 15
    TX packets 155182  bytes 56480649 (53.8 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.118  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::ec0f:202c:4cbb:c152  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:7f:32:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 7045  bytes 1171763 (1.1 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 239  bytes 20640 (20.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And `iwconfig` output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"PiWiFi"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: 84:D8:1B:A0:D8:A5
          Bit Rate=24 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:258  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Do I have to worry for something? My web server is 24/7 in the same spot. Signal is 4G full. As you can see i am getting IP address and from wlan0 from the TP-Link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that all your RX errors are "frame" errors, which means incomplete or corrupted network frames were received by the network interface and discarded. Unlike "dropped" (which mean you receive frames you don't expect) or "overrun" (which means the system is overloaded), these errors cannot be fixed by configuration.

Some amount of frame errors is normal for a wireless interface. The signal strength reported by your 4G dongle is a cumulative value, where "full" probably means something like "signal is good 99% of the time". RX errors are instantaneous events which happen if the transmission takes place during the other 1%.